# How Do I Keep An Arc News Server Running On EC2 After The SSH Session Is Closed?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a HN Clone based on these steps:

http://nicholasblee.com/blog/hacker-news-clone-on-a-free-aws-ec2-instance-wapache-reverse-proxy-server-20-min-install/#

Basically these three steps are required to get "ready to serve port 8080":

```
$ mzscheme -f as.scm
arc> (load "news.arc")
arc> (nsv)
```

The issue is, once the terminal session is closed, in spite of the running EC2 instance, 8080 does not respond. (it works fine as long as the ssh is running)

How do I get this to run in the background AFTER the ssh is terminated? Shd i place these commands in some instance startup or something? How do I do it?

Comment: I have found a working solution for this: here it is: (picked up from this long <a href="http://75.125.15.34/item?id=11000">thread</a> on arclanguage forum) 

Basically you need to cd to the arc directory, and do a screen on mzscheme. and then, in the window that opens, you can type out the load and nsv.  Then do a Ctrl- A D to detach the screen.

YOu are done. Even when the terminal is closed, since screen executes as a separate thread, you are good. you can resume by typing screen -r on the terminal any time.